# Como fazer um botão com cantos arredondados em C# (Winforms )

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando customizar a aparência de um botão, basicamente estou tentando customizar as bordas, background, cor da fonte e arredondar os cantos do botão. **Consegui fazer tudo exceto arredondar os cantos do botão**. Tentei seguir um [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx), mas acabou que no lugar de criar com cantos arredondados estava criando uma elipse.

```
public class Button : System.Windows.Forms.Button
    {
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        Color bc = Color.Black;
        Color bg = Color.Red;
        Color fc = Color.White;
        StringFormat formatter = new StringFormat();

        base.OnPaint(e);
        formatter.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        formatter.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(0, 0, e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Height);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bg), e.ClipRectangle);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, bc, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(fc), rectangle, formatter);
    }
}
```

Preciso de ajuda para conseguir arredondar as borda.

Comment: O link que você colocou não tem tutorial algum. Experimentou mudar os valores? Conforme você vai deformando uma elipse ela pode se tornar um retângulo com cantos arredondados.

Comment: @Bacco o ideal seria um codigo em c#, a ide que estou usando e o windows 2013 , o projeto é em win32 vi muita coisa em css, mas para mim não interessa.

Comment: @bigown O link que eu postei tem um trecho de código, se copiar ele e colocar no projeto ele gera uma elipse, já mudei os valores, quando mudei a altura da elipse aumentou, mas fora isso não mudou muita coisa. Testei vários valores. 5, 20, 2, 200. Mas só tive como resultado a elipse mesmo.

Comment: @Bacco a ide é Visual Studio 2013, informei errado. Qual seria sua sugestão para tag?

Comment: Pelo que eu vi do seu exemplo, eu tenho a impressão que c# e winforms seriam as tags corretas, independentemente da IDE usada. Win32 não me parece ser o que você procura, mas como eu disse, é apenas impressão minha baseado no que eu li, pode ser que eu não tenha entendido algo. PS: Win32 é a api "antiga" do windows, não parece ser o que você quer.

Comment: (claro que boa parte do que você está usando pode chamar internamente a Win32, ou a Win64, por exemplo, mas acho que o importante é o WinForms mesmo, como você deixou agora).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No site da [MSDN tem um exemplo que está funcionando](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/ca07e19f-a3e2-4a8d-b9a0-8983bb83914b/customizar-boto?forum=vscsharppt), o trecho de código abaixo foi retirado de lá.

Mudei o nome da função `SuArredondaRect` para `BorderRadius`, mas está funcionando. Para que esse código funcione o `pCanto` tem que ser maior que 0.

```
class Transform
{
    public static GraphicsPath BorderRadius(Rectangle pRect, int pCanto, bool pTopo, bool pBase) {
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();

        if (pTopo) {
            gp.AddArc(pRect.X - 1, pRect.Y - 1, pCanto, pCanto, 180, 90);
            gp.AddArc(pRect.X + pRect.Width - pCanto, pRect.Y - 1, pCanto, pCanto, 270, 90);
        } else {
            // Se não arredondar o topo, adiciona as linhas para poder fechar o retangulo junto com
            // a base arredondada
            gp.AddLine(pRect.X - 1, pRect.Y - 1, pRect.X + pRect.Width, pRect.Y - 1);
        }

        if (pBase) {
            gp.AddArc(pRect.X + pRect.Width - pCanto, pRect.Y + pRect.Height - pCanto, pCanto, pCanto, 0, 90);
            gp.AddArc(pRect.X - 1, pRect.Y + pRect.Height - pCanto, pCanto, pCanto, 90, 90);
        } else {
            // Se não arredondar a base, adiciona as linhas para poder fechar o retangulo junto com
            // o topo arredondado. Adiciona da direita para esquerda pois é na ordem contrária que 
            // foi adicionado os arcos do topo. E pra fechar o retangulo tem que desenhar na ordem :
            //  1 - Canto Superior Esquerdo
            //  2 - Canto Superior Direito
            //  3 - Canto Inferior Direito 
            //  4 - Canto Inferior Esquerdo.
            gp.AddLine(pRect.X + pRect.Width, pRect.Y + pRect.Height, pRect.X - 1, pRect.Y + pRect.Height);
        }

        return gp;
    }
}
```

Para funcionar basta chamar o método `BorderRadius` da classe `Transform` (o trecho de código acima).
Um exemplo de chamada com base no código atual seria:

```
public class Button : System.Windows.Forms.Button
    {
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        Color bc = Color.Black;
        Color bg = Color.Red;
        Color fc = Color.White;
        StringFormat formatter = new StringFormat();

        base.OnPaint(e);
        formatter.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        formatter.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(0, 0, e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Height);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bg), e.ClipRectangle);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, bc, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(fc), rectangle, formatter);

        // BorderRadius é uma variável do tipo inteiro que define a quantidade que a borda deve ser arredondada.
        if (BorderRadius > 0) {
            GraphicsPath gp = Transform.BorderRadius(ClientRectangle, BorderRadius, true, true);
            this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(gp);
        }
    }
}
```